# Where is the save data location in Windows for Pokemon Uranium?

Tags: pokemon-uranium

I encountered an error trying to manage some save files in Pokemon Uranium. Since I'm somewhat technical, I'd like to look into this a bit myself but I'm not able to find where the save files are. Where is the location of the save data in a Windows environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save data is found in:

C:/users/[your name]/saved games/pokemon uranium.

The file from file 1 Is uranium.rxdata

The file from file 2 is uranium_2.rxdata

The file from file 3 is uranium_3.rxdata

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that I had moved the saved games library to a different disk. Found it now though!